# CKEditor : copy and paste email address that contains IMG tags

Tags: ckeditor, copy-paste

I having issue in copy and paste in CKEditor. Copied value contains img tag  -

```
Post : "<img/* /src=/images/star.png"
```

When you copy and paste normally it works, but in my application there is link called as "Copy Email Address" on some post and then paste in ckeditor its pasting as an image.

Is there a way to tell CKEditor to treat this as plain text and dont execute html tags ? Do I need to change onPaste or beforePaste methods in ckeditor.js file.?

I really wanted to paste this as normal text. Is it possible ?

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me.. using 4.5.9. which version did you try on?

Comment: Yeah when you copy and paste normally it works, but in my application there is link called as "Copy Email Address" on some post and then paste in ckeditor its pasting as an image.

Comment: Is there a way to tell CKEditor to treat this as plain text and dont execute html tags ? Do I need to change onPaste or beforePaste methods in ckeditor.js file ?

Comment: you may try putting your code in <code>...</code> or <pre></pre> tag.. Yo can also convert < to &lt; and > to &gt; using javascript, it may also solve the problem.